# URL Title Ajax Validation

Tags: javascript, ajax, validation

I'm running an install of EE v3.5.14 and I'm trying to replicate some of the functionality of the old "Title Master" add-on, but I'm hitting a snag.

I've got my extension to hook to the custom_field_modify_data($ft, $method, $data) extension hook, and have it so that when $ft->field_name is 'url_title' and $method is 'validate' it checks for whether the URL title is taken for that channel already, and if so to append an integer increment afterwards.

All looks to be working just fine so far, however I'm hitting a snag with the channel entry form's ajax validation.

When the ajax runs it calls the fieldtype's validation, and this does trigger my hook (I've tested with a dump/die). However if I have it update the $ft object's values it does not update the 'url_title' form input field. I'm guessing I'd need to run some javascript to handle that, but I have no clue how to do that.

Below is my code so far:

```
function testApi(EE_Fieldtype $ft, $method, $data)
{
    if ($ft->field_name == 'url_title' && $method == 'validate')
    {
        $url_title = $data[0];
        $increment = $this->getIncrement();

        while($this->checkUrlTitle($data[0]))
        {
            $data[0] = $url_title . $increment++;
        }

        ee()->db->update(
            'title_master',
            array(
                'increment' => $increment
            ),
            array(
                'channel_id' => ee()->input->post('channel_id')
            )
        );

        $ft->settings['field_data'] = $data[0];
    }

    return $data;
}
```

How can I get this to update the form input field for the 'url_title'?